# Create a dynamic table in As3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic

I need to create a table within a dynamic text box in a media piece. I am aware that html can be used to create the table but I am not sure how to go about it. Throughout the piece the user is inputting text answers which are then stored as variables. My problem is that I can't find anywhere that mentions how to create a table in a dynamic text box that will display the user inputted text from before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observe from the following part of ActionScript 3 API Reference by Adobe, you cannot insert tables into text fields:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText

The `table` tag, as we know it from HTML, is simply not supported. You will have to resort to implementing your own table rendering system and integrate it into your already existing context using `flash.text` package which provides some advanced text rendering and measuring capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I sense a lot of frustrating text boxes in my future.

Comment: You can use regex to extract the information. First the lines, then the cells (for each line) and create a table manually or with a Flash component or using Flex.

Comment: @user2455748 No need to be frustrated - text boxes in Flash are not more than just that - text boxes. You can have italic and bold text in these, and floating images, but that's pretty much it. You want something more advanced, you implement it yourself :-)